# How to trigger action on primefaces datatable row expansion only not rowToggle

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

I need the action to be triggered when expanding a row only, not when collapsing it, so basically rowToggle event doesn't work for me as it executes in both expanding and collapsing events

```html
<p:ajax event="rowToggle" listener="#{queryStudiesBean.onRowToggle}" />
```

I need somthing like this, but with `event="rowExpansion"`, but no `rowExpansion` event exists, so how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use visibility property of the `ToggleEvent`:

```java
public void onRowToggle(org.primefaces.event.ToggleEvent event) {
  if (event.getVisibility() == Visibility.VISIBLE) {
    // Row was expanded
  }
}
```